# PHP -Iterate letters in PHP with a custom format

Tags: php, excel, loops, letter

I need to iterate letters in PHP in the following order. A, AA, AB, AC-AZ, B,BA,BB,BC,BD...BZ..

What I have right now is like the Excel columns from a-z, then aa,ab,ac. I'm currently struggling the find a logical way to do the requirement.

Please note that I need to exhaust the range 1 to 200 before i transition to aa.

For example

```
1a
2a
3a
```

up to

```
200a
1aa
2aa
3aa
```

up to

```
200aa
1ab
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
public function createColumnsArray($end_column, $first_letters = '')
{
    $columns = array();
    $length = strlen($end_column);
    $letters = range('A', 'Z');

    // Iterate over 26 letters.
    foreach ($letters as $letter) {
        // Paste the $first_letters before the next.
        $column = $first_letters . $letter;

        // Add the column to the final array.
        $columns[] = $column;

        // If it was the end column that was added, return the columns.
        if ($column == $end_column)
            return $columns;
    }

    // Add the column children.
    foreach ($columns as $column) {
        // Don't iterate if the $end_column was already set in a previous iteration.
        // Stop iterating if you've reached the maximum character length.
        if (!in_array($end_column, $columns) && strlen($column) < $length) {
            $new_columns = $this->createColumnsArray($end_column, $column);
            // Merge the new columns which were created with the final columns array.
            $columns = array_merge($columns, $new_columns);
        }
    }

    return $columns;
}
```

Comment: It's far from clear what the sequence you quoted is. If you simply mean the excel columns, in the order they appear, you should say so. And anyone who creates a spreadsheet with more than 30 columns should be left to clean up their own mess.

Comment: I'm sorry if the sorting wasn't clear. But basically from a series of 1 to 200. The output should be as follows. 1A-200A then 1AA -200AA upto 1AZ-200AZ before we move on to B

Comment: Try this: https://3v4l.org/HFo3J (The code evaluation there errors when I go over the full range of 1 to 200 and A to Z, so I used only 1 to 20 and A to C in there, but I suppose it should work fine in a "real" PHP environment and with the actual values.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$letters1 = range('A', 'Z');
$letters2 = array_merge([''], range('A', 'Z'));

foreach($letters1 as $l1) {
    foreach($letters2 as $l2) {
        for($i=1; $i<=200; ++$i) {
            $result[] = $i.$l1.$l2;
        }
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

The "trick" I am using here is to put an empty string into the second "letter" array. That way, we can just use nested loops, and concatenate three parts - the number, the first letter, and the second letter - *every* time, without having to treat the values that consist only of number and *one* letter, any differently.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are looking you will have to 2 arrays for letters and 1 for the numbers.

Because you want a letter alone before moving to the AA AB etc. We have to run the first array with only a letter.

```
$letters = array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z");
$start = 1;
$stop = 200;

foreach ($letters as $letter1){
    
    // print the first letter with number only.
    for($i = $start; $i <= $stop; $i++){
            print $i.$letter1 . "\n";
        }
    
    foreach($letters as $letter2){
        for($i = $start; $i <= $stop; $i++){
            print $i.$letter1.$letter2. "\n";
        }
    }
    
}
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: I've tried this one but after A, the next letter is B. Should be AA, but will try to customize this one out to AA instead of B

Comment: Did you run it in PHP?, the logic is 1A, 2A... 1AA, 1AB 200AB, 1C...